# Do Varadero or Havana airports have shops which sell cigars and alcohol?

Tags: airports, shopping, cuba, hav

What are restrictions for cigars and alcohol for departing tourists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Havana airport there is a lot of shops with cigars, alcohol and all the souvenirs, music, jewelry, t-shirts etc. Prices are generally the same or slightly higher than in the city (I think all of the shops are owned by the government anyway). They have generally better assortment before proceeding to the gate. I could pay in some shops with my Mastercard, but not in all of them.

According to [www.taxfreetravel.com](http://www.taxfreetravel.com/Duty-Free-Cuban-Cigars/) rules for cigars are

- For those wishing to take up to 20 Cuban cigars these is no documentation required.
- For those taking up to 50 Cuban cigars – They must be sealed, bearing an official hologram, unopened and in their original packaging.
- For quantities of 50 cigars and over. Again they must be sealed, bearing an official hologram, unopened and in their original packaging. You will need to produce an invoice/bill of sale from the place of purchase which itself must be licensed to sell cigars. The total amount of the invoice detailing the amount of cigars must not exceed 5,000 (five thousand) CUC ( Cuban Convertible Peso).

Comment: For the record Varadero airport also has shops for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Varadero airport has enough shops which sell cigars, rum, honey, coffee and other souvenirs. Prices for cigars are higher than in the cities. For example, Santa Clara had probably the best prices for cigars - 1 Guantanamera cigar costs about $1.3 while $2 in the airport, $11 for Guantanamera package ($15-$20 in airport), $4 for Romeo y Julieta cigar ($5 in airport). Other prices in the airport - $5.55 for Havana club 3 years, $4 for honey, $3 for chocolate. There is currency exchange service near duty free shops or you can pay in EUR or GBP. Wifi is available with ETECSA card.